# Passing a value to a function within React map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, buttongroup

I've got an object

```
    const opt = [
  {
    name: "VAS",
    lines: ["."]
  },
  {
    name: "PACK",
    lines: ["1", "2"]
  },
  {
    name: "RET",
    lines: ["A"]
  }
];
```

And I'm trying to create a button group where all buttons are dynamically generated based on `opt.name` like this:

```
  <ButtonGroup
      color="primary"
      aria-label="large outlined primary button group"
    >
      {opt.map((elem, index) => (
        <Button onClick={changeState(elem.name)}>{elem.name} </Button>
      ))}
    </ButtonGroup>
```

The function itself sets the react state :

```
  const changeState = (x) => {
setValue(x);
```

};

For some reason this causes infinite re-render loop:

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-neumann-0t7qq?file=/src/App.js:292-391

The desired outcome is for the setValue to update the state based on button (opt.name ) I clicked on .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking `changeState` immediately. Eg:

```
<Button onClick={changeState(elem.name)}>{elem.name} </Button>
```

is the same sort of thing as

```
const clickHandler = changeState(elem.name);
// ...
return (
  <Button onClick={clickHandler}>{elem.name} </Button>
);
```

Change to:

```
  {opt.map((elem, index) => (
    <Button onClick={() => changeState(elem.name)}>{elem.name} </Button>
  ))}
```

Comment: It works, but I have no idea why. Shouldn't changeState be only invoked on click of the button anyway?

Comment: @PeterSlanina you are saying you want the handler to be the return value of  `changeState(...)` which is probably not what you want.